# prevent jquery alert from showing on submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using this jquery code to warn users from navigating away before they complete our online application. We have a lot of users that hit the back button (not knowing it's a navigation short cut) when they are in a menu/list field and lose all the data they've entered in the application. The problem is, I can't figure out how to keep the warning from showing when they hit the submit button.

I've looked at several other similar posts on this site, but I'm not able to get them to work either. Actually for most of those I couldn't even get the pop up to work. I'm not very familiar with jquery so it's probably something simple that I'm missing. (I actually have another solution that I was working on here : http://www.citizensmemorial.com/careers/online-app.html

```
<script> function setConfirmUnload(on) {

     window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;

}

function unloadMessage() {

     return 'You have started filling out this application.' +
        ' If you navigate away from this page without' +           
        ' first saving your data, the changes will be' +
        ' lost.';

}</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

     $(':input',document.form1).bind(
         "change", function() { 
              setConfirmUnload(true);
         }
      ); // Prevent accidental navigation away

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reversed your validation so you dont have to parse anything to `setConfirmUnload` when setting the confirm.

```
function setConfirmUnload(disable) {
     window.onbeforeunload = disable ? null : unloadMessage;
}

function unloadMessage() {
    return 'You have started filling out this application.' +
        ' If you navigate away from this page without' +           
        ' first saving your data, the changes will be' +
        ' lost.';
}
setConfirmUnload();
jQuery(function($) { // <-- Dom is ready (same as $(document).ready(function($) {)
    $("form").on("submit", setConfirmUnload);
});
```

And i have bound the `setConfirmUnload` to the forms submit handler. The first argument in the call is an `jQueryEvent Object` This will validate to true when testing.

[You can try a simple demo here](http://jsbin.com/ecelec/1/embed?live).

---

If you want to first activate the unload-handler when anything is entered into an input you can use:

```
var $inputs = $("form :input").on("change", function() {
    setConfirmUnload();
    $inputs.off("change"); // <-- remove the event form all elements.
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in our content management system (there's a place to enter code for templates) and I'm getting this error:    An error occurred during editing: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.